# I have an interview but the job description is no longer available. Can I ask the recruiter for a copy?

Tags: job-search, job-description

I usually prepare the interview based on the job descriptions to underline my skills and the responsibilities.

I know the best idea is to keep a copy of all job descriptions I apply to, but the company already eliminated the job  description from their web site. Is there a correct way to ask the HR recruiter for a copy without coming across as unprepared?

Comment: Check the Internet Archive if you didn't yet. They might have a copy of the page you can't find.

Answer (score 13):

It's pretty simple and there's nothing wrong with asking. Plenty of people don't make a habit of saving job descriptions and as you've discovered sometimes companies take them offline before candidates get the chance to. The only way for you to come across as unprepared is to wait too long to ask about this or to walk into the interview having forgotten the details in the job description.  Simply say the following in an email:

> While preparing for my interview of the Xth I wanted to review the job description but noticed it has disappeared from the site. Could you send me a copy?

You can embellish the request if you like but you really don't have to overcomplicate it. If you have yet to confirm the interview time you'd do that in the same mail and open with that instead.

Comment: These people spend all day reading & writing emails and sending off job descriptions.  It's really no big deal to them & they'll probably forget all about it in 5 minutes.  Don't bother trying to come up with elaborate explanations, just send a concise & polite email.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a correct way to ask the HR recruiter for a copy without
>   coming across as unprepared?

You are unprepared.

Just be honest. Ask for a copy and offer your thanks.